# to use GCM, each device will need to register?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am very confused to use GCM service, I have sender id, api key and registered emulator so got registration id.

Now, next what to do ?
I want that whever new version is available, user get notification or alert dialog which will show new version is available. Then 2 buttons, update now and update later.

I am using ASP.NET server.

Answer (score 0):

By using gcm sender id,you will use in android ie client side and  server browser api in server side say php side. So when a device opens,it will create gcm register id at server side and intermediate is gcm account and it will monitor the device.so you can send notification from server to client. For same device,only unique gcm registration id will be generated.

See this tutorial

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: ohk,,, so I will need to save reg id in my database and later on, whenever i want to push notification, i will need to fire message from server side to all reg id. am i rite?

Comment: and it asks for google account, so its mean each user will need to add google account in their mobile device ???

Comment: generally in default to download an app in market, user will create an account, so it takes that account id from settings->add account. if user doesnt have account means,you can do some stuffs to alert to create an account.@JeetenParmar

Comment: yes, i was thinking d same thing. It is not a gud feature i think cz i ask for account.

Comment: lol.yeah but generally if you add in market means,surely user should have account to access android playstore,at that time this is beneficial.@JeetenParmar